# crictl images --digest does not display digests in the Kind node

Tags: kubernetes, kind, crictl

I upload the docker image using:

`kind load docker-image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.0`

After that, I go to the Kind node:

`docker exec -it kind-control-plane bash`

And I execute:

```
root@kind-control-plane:/# crictl images --digests
IMAGE                                                 TAG                  DIGEST              IMAGE ID            SIZE
...
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                                       3.5.1-0              <none>              25f8c7f3da61c       98.9MB
k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen         v1.0                 <none>              17e55ec30f203       48MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver                             v1.23.4              <none>              0e16468a4aa36       79.6MB
....
```

And for all images, the DIGEST column contains only `<none>`

Why?

This is important to me, because if I create a pod in the cluster, the container of which is indicated with the indication of the digest, then it is pulled from outside. I suspect it may be related.

Comment: This question does not seem appropriate for this site, Try raising the issue https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Before 0.14, digests are not created for images loaded with `kind load`.

Should be fixed in 0.14
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2734